# Convert a capital case string to camel case using shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to convert a Capital case word to camel case using shell script. e.g. `ProjectAssignment` should be converted to `projectAssignment`.

```
echo "project assignment" | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

This produces output as : `Project Assignment`

On the similar lines, I want to convert `ProjectAssignment` to `projectAssignment`.

Comment: I want to convert ProjectAssignment to projectAssignment.

Comment: Your question is confusing - you mention one string but then your script contains another string and it's not clear how this one should be changed.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Edited my question according to your suggestions.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the desired output is for the input `project assignment` (with a space).

Comment: Below answer has solved my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it but your question isn't useful to others unless the examples you have given are clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with gnu-sed:

```
s='ProjectAssignment'
echo "$s" | sed 's/^[A-Z]/\L&/'

projectAssignment
```

`^[A-Z]` will match only the first letter if it is uppercase.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you very much @anubhava.

Comment: This gives me `LProjectAssignment`

Comment: That means you're not using `gnu sed`

Comment: I am on macos, and have the sed command. Is GNU sed only available on linux or what?

Comment: I am also on mac and have installed `gnu sed` using `home brew`

Comment: Then I need to make everyone in my team install it. And some of them are on windows machines. Oh well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty awk command to convert any string to camelCase (no spaces):

```
camelCaseString=$( echo "$originalString" | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=""};{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){ if(j==1){$j=tolower($j)} else {$j=toupper(substr($j,1,1)) tolower(substr($j,2)) }}}1')
```

Example:

```
originalString="This is my normal string"
echo $camelCaseString
thisIsMyNormalString
```